Lenovo m11 physical keyboard doesen't support Icelandic alphabet
I have a Lenovo m11 tablet and when I use physical keyboard it seems that that Lenovo doesn't support Icelandic alphabet. The letters that are missing are þ,æ and ö. On screen keyboard is OK and all settings are OK. It seems that I cannot use a physical keyboard.
Do you have solution for this?

Which keyboard layout are you using? Which characters are problematic?

The letters that are missing are þ,æ,ö. All language settings are up to date. Tried three diffrent keyboards yesterday always same problem. This is propably software problem

Which language and keyboard layout are you using? Please also add a screenshot of regedit key HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload.

Please [edit] your question and add (output from) powershell -noprofile -command Get-WinUserLanguageList as well as reg query "HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload". Please refrain from posting screenshots if possible: copy the actual text from an open cmd window, paste it into the question, then format it as code.
